# Most efficient way to detect collision of two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, collision-detection

I'm using [Jquery Collision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/) to detect two objects overlapping each other. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7PEp/1/) of the problem.
(apologies for including `jquery collision` script in HTML, couldn't find other way)

Click anywhere in the gray container to move the green div over the white div.

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hit_list;
    $(".container").click(function () {

        $(".menu").stop().animate({
            left: "+=100px"
        }, 300, function () {
            $(".menu").animate({
                left: "0"
            }, 800);
        });
        //Test for collision
        hit_list = $(".menu").collision(".test");
        if (hit_list.length != 0) {
            alert("welcome Earthling!");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with my method is that, it doesn't detect collision every time. Even though it passes over the white division fine, the `alert` isn't displayed everytime.

Am I going wrong anywhere in checking for collision? Is there a better/more efficient method to detect collisions during `animation` ?

Comment: I only get the alert when I double-click the area.

Comment: The time `hit_list = $(".menu").collision(".test");` is getting executed, the animation has not yet caused a collision. You need either a listener which watches the move of `.menu` or a timeout mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery animate has a step callback (https://api.jquery.com/animate/), it gets executed after each step of the animation.

Use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hit_list;
    $(".container").click(function () {

        $(".menu").stop().animate({
            left: "+=100px"
        }, {
           duration: 300,
           complete: function () {
               $(".menu").animate({
                   left: "0"
               }, 800);
           },
           step: function(){
               //Test for collision
               hit_list = $(".menu").collision(".test");
               if (hit_list.length != 0) {
                   alert("welcome Earthling!");
               }
           }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: This solution works fine. But, it displays alert twice. Why does that happen?

Comment: The `step` function is called in every step of the animation. So in fact it might display the alert many more times. If you want it to display the alert only the first time it detects the collision you could set up a flag before the animation starts. Then when you detect a collision in a step callback turn on the flag, and also in the `step` function check if the flag hasn't been turned on already.

Comment: That'd do, my only concern is that instead of alert there will be a more complicated function which needs to be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/y7PEp/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hit_list;
    var hits=0;
    $(".container").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        function checkCollision() {
           //Test for collision
            hit_list = $(".menu").collision(".test");
            if (hit_list.length != 0) {
                hits++;
                $(".menu").html(hits+ ' hits');
            } 
        }

        $(".menu").stop().animate({
            left: "100px"
        }, 300, function () {
            checkCollision();
            $(".menu").animate({
                left: "0"
            }, 800);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly as long as the object is within reach of 1 click, as soon as you move the red obstacle further away and require more clicks for collision it doesnt register a hit every time.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. Can you change the fiddle to explain the problem?